# Refreshing _LoginPartial only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im using MVC4 anf knockoutjs in my application. I am using a jquery popup for user login and after successful login i want to referesh "_LoginPartial" only not the complete page. Currenlty im using the following code :

```
//Ajax call from JS file
 $.get('@Url.Action("PartialUpdate", "Account")',{}, function (data) {
                      $("#_LoginPartial").html(data);
                  });

// in Account Controller
public ActionResult PartialUpdate(){
                return PartialView("_LoginPartial");
        }
```

in the above code it is returning complete login page at first and second time its returning the appropriate data but the "_LoginPartial" is not updating. Can someone guide me in this...........

Answer (score 0):

Try switching .get to .ajax

```
$.ajax({ url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))", type: "POST", cache: false, async: true, data: { id: 'id' }, success: function (result) { $(".Content").html(result);  } });
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for reply. I think i found the actual issue. I am using ajax call to get user login  and issue come here that 'Request.IsAuthenticated' is still false. Im trying with 'FormsAuthenticationTicket' right now.